# Got error (pre-receive hook declined) with dokku

Tags: git, dokku

I got a error when pushing to my VPS with Ubuntu and Dokku

```
$ git push dokku master
Counting objects: 1104, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1057/1057), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1104/1104), 2.38 MiB | 2.45 MiB/s, done.
Total 1104 (delta 346), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building TransCRM from herokuish...
remote: repository name component must match "a-z0-9(?:[._][a-z0-9](?:-[a-z0-9]))"
To dokku@nnn.nn.nn.nn:TransCRM
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@nnn.nn.nn.nn:TransCRM'
```

this did`t help (I find this solve on github in Dokku repo)

```
 sudo wget -O /etc/init/docker.conf https://raw.github.com/dotcloud/docker/master/contrib/init/upstart/docker.conf
    sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: Nearly 3 years and not a valid solution!

Answer (score 0):

`remote: repository name component must match "a-z0-9(?:[._][a-z0-9](?:-[a-z0-9]))"`

This line means that the dokku's container service names must match this regex. So a name like "TransCRM" won't work, but "transcrm" would work. My Intuition for this would be that subdomains don't normally match uppercase vs lowercase, so dokku enforces lowercase for consistency.